# Save a result containing HoldForm to a file

Tags: output-formatting, output, save

This is the workflow I have. Basically, I want the outputs of the polynomials I computed are in a specific order. (It is not the same one here, this is just an example.).

```
f[1] = 1;
f[2] = x;
f[3] = x + y;
f[n_] := Expand[f[n - 1]*(x + 2 y - 3)]

f[4]
```

> -3 x + x^2 - 3 y + 3 x y + 2 y^2

```
monomials = MonomialList[f[4]]
```

> {x^2, 3 x y, -3 x, 2 y^2, -3 y}

```
First /@ CoefficientRules[f[4]]
```

> {{2, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, 2}, {0, 1}}

```
Sort@(First /@ CoefficientRules[f[4]])
```

> {{0, 1}, {0, 2}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 0}}

```
permutation = Ordering[First /@ CoefficientRules[f[4]]]
```

> {5, 4, 3, 2, 1}

```
SortedMonomials = monomials[[permutation]]
```

> {-3 y, 2 y^2, -3 x, 3 x y, x^2}

```
result=Plus @@@ HoldForm[Evaluate[SortedMonomials]]
```

> -3 y+2 y^2-3 x+3 x y+x^2

But when I use `Save` to save the last result above, it will be `result = HoldForm[-3*y + 2*y^2 - 3*x + 3*x*y + x^2]` in the saved .txt file.

I want the content in the file to be `result = -3*y + 2*y^2 - 3*x + 3*x*y + x^2`.

Is there any way to achieve my requirement, only use MMA?

Answer (score 1):

Is there some reason you are avoiding [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html)?  That will work like this:

```
x = "Fail!";
test := y + x

Save["foo.m", test]
FilePrint["foo.m"]
```

> ```
> test := y + x
>
> x = "Fail!"
> ```

If for some reason that won't work you can use [`Unevaluated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unevaluated.html):

```
Remove[x, y, test]

y = "Fail!";
test = Unevaluated[y + x];

Save["bar.m", test]
FilePrint["bar.m"]
```

> ```
> test = y + x
>
> y = "Fail!"
> ```

Comment: That works. I don't know why I didn't use := at the first place. I will think about it. Thank you.

Comment: I see the reason. In fact, I am defining a sequence of polynomials. Each of these polynomials will be determined by some computation. The outputs of these computations are polynomials. I tried to rearrange the terms and use `HoldForm` to make sure they appear as I expected. In this case, using `SetDelayed` is not the point, because I still need to use `HoldForm`. But after the whole computation are done and the sequence of polynomials are defined, I want to save the results into a file.

Comment: @user565739 Would you edit your question to give a condensed yet complete example of your workflow?  I am not sure I understand.  What exactly are the "results" and in what way are they the product of computation?

Comment: Ok, I will edit my question.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are saving to a text file, how about convert to string first, for example:

`pl = ToString[#] &[HoldForm[test = x + y]]; Save["file.txt", pl]`

Answer (score 1):

One can use `Block` to prevent `Plus` from evaluating until after `result` is defined.

```
SortedMonomials = {-3 y, 2 y^2, -3 x, 3 x y, x^2};

Block[{Plus},
 result = Plus @@ SortedMonomials;
 ]

Save["/tmp/foo.txt", result]

FilePrint["/tmp/foo.txt"]
```

> `result = -3*y + 2*y^2 - 3*x + 3*x*y + x^2`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have values for x and y defined, hence the need for `HoldForm`:

```
x = 1;
y = 2;

Block[{x, y},
 test = y + x;
 Save["file.txt", test]]
```

Comment: No, x and y are variables as in a polynomial. The variable `test` is a polynomial.